The meaning of the formula finding the area of a triangle in coordinates
I was trying to find out the area of a triangle given three points in the coordinates (I didn’t search on the internet, I later found out that this was already done by someone). I got the formula as below:
$$ A=\frac{1}{2}(x_2y_3-x_3y_2+x_3y_1-x_1y_3+x_1y_2-x_2y_1) $$
Where $(x_1,y_1)$ is the coordinates of the first point, and so on.
And I have rewritten it in an absurd looking way:
$$ A=\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}\times\vec{y}\cdot\vec{1}$$
Where $\vec{x}= \langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle$, $\vec{y}=\langle y_1,y_2,y_3\rangle $, $\vec{1}=\langle 1,1,1\rangle$
This formula looks astonishingly similar to $A=\frac{1}{2}bh$.
I knew how to algebraically prove this, but when I saw the cross product suddenly appeared, I thought there must be a way to somehow prove it using vectors.
So, my question is: How to prove the formula above using vectors? (Edit) Or to be more precise, what exactly does $\mathbf{\vec{x}\boldsymbol{\times}\vec{y}}$  represent in this case?

$$
\frac{1}{2}(\vec x\times\vec y)\cdot\vec1=
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat i&\hat j& \hat z\ x_1 &x_2&x_3\y_1&y_2&y_3
\end{vmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1\1\1
\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1\ x_1 &x_2&x_3\y_1&y_2&y_3
\end{vmatrix}
$$ Now, absolute value of the last expression is the area of the triangle, proved here
